# how to set unique attribute in a model row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, activeadmin

I have a model Competitor like this

```
class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin_user
  has_many :companies
  attr_accessible :admin_user_id, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5
  validates :admin_user_id, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :admin_user_id, :message => "This user has yet a competitors list"

end
```

C1, c2,.. are the id of companies. Selected from a drop down list. How can I validate the uniqueness of a row? 
(i.e. is not possible to have two or more equals companies for an admin user BUT they can be empties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own validation method that would enforce this.

```
class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin_user
  has_many :companies
  attr_accessible :admin_user_id, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5
  validates :admin_user_id, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :admin_user_id, :message => "This user has yet a competitors list"

  validate :check_companies

  def check_companies
    #[do your checks]
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, then in check_companies do something like: if c1 == c2 return false (ecc..) ... else true, right? (i must rerturn a boolean value? -> "validate" accept only boolean value?)

Comment: Exactly! did you really need help? ;)